# @NotNull for Double in XML Validation

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, annotations, bean-validation

I need to validate the structure of an XML in input using JSR-303 annotations. So I want my XML to contain all the required tags, and I accept if the XML tags contain no value at all.
So there must be all the tags and they can be empty.

The problem is that if @NotNull annotation works well for Strings (so I can have the xml tag without value in it), for Double variables I cannot use it, because if I empty the tag, it returns me the error like I delete the tag also.

For istance:

```
<extTag>
  <myString>Hello</myString>   -> @NotNull String myString; -> OK!
</extTag>

<extTag>
  <myString></myString>        -> @NotNull String myString; -> OK!
</extTag>

<extTag>
                               -> @NotNull String myString; -> ERROR!
</extTag>
```

For Double I would like to have the same control, but when the value is null I get the error!

```
<extTag>
  <myDouble>12.00</myDouble>   -> @NotNull Double myDouble; -> OK!
</extTag>

<extTag>
  <myDouble></myDouble>        -> @NotNull Double myDouble; -> ERROR!
</extTag>

<extTag>
                               -> @NotNull Double myDouble; -> ERROR!
</extTag>
```

I can I get the same behaviour od strings for Double variables **using annotations**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use a diferent technique to validate `XML` structure, use a `XML Schema Definition (XSD)` or iterate the hole document with a parser.

I think you are a little confused with `XML` and Bean Validation, remember `XML` stores a `String` representation of the Bean values, and that *JSR-303* is about value validation:

- For `String` you have an empty value representation and this: `<myString></myString>` is just fine because is equivalent to this `""`.
- For `Double` there is no empty representation, so this `<myDouble></myDouble>` is a null value.